# Find all odd functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that satisfy $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all functions: $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that satisfy all the following three conditions:
>
> 1. $f(-x)=-f(x)$
> 2. $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$
> 3. $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$

I assume $f(x)=x$ satisfies the conditions. I could prove $f(0)=0 $ and $f(n)=n$ for all $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$, then I didn't know how to go any further.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: f satifsies all three conditions , i edited the probelm, thank you!!

Comment: What can you say about $f(1/2)$? What about $f(3/2)$ and $f(5/2)$? What about $f(2/3)$ and $f(2/5)$? How far can you take this?

Comment: @Arthur:   I think that gets us $f(x)=x$ at all the rationals, which is why I suggested the problem should specify the function is continuous.  Dan Vellerman thinks we can do better.

Comment: @RossMillikan I was asking Beginner, hoping they would continue the fine work they did with the integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the given conditions you can prove that $f(x) = x$ for all $x$.  Hint:  Suppose that for some number $a$, $f(a) = b$.  The given conditions allow you to compute $f(-a)$, $f(a+1)$, and $f(1/a)$ (if $a \ne 0$).  Use these steps repeatedly to reach other values.  If you can find two different sequences of steps that lead to the value of $f$ at the same input, then you can set the results equal to each other and solve for $b$.

Comment: I didn't get what you said , i can find the values of $f(-a)$ , $f(a+1)$ and $f(\frac{1}{a})$ in terms of $b$ , then can you please explain the rest of your solution to me

Comment: Next step:  You can compute things like $f(1/(a+1))$ or $f((1/a) + 1)$.  Keep going, using the rules repeatedly.

Comment: And? , Please clarify your idea to me , I don't seem to get what you wanna do, i feel like counting random numbers in terms of b and i have no idea why

Comment: If you keep going, you will eventually find that you have two different formulas for the same value of $f$.  Set them equal to each other and solve for $b$.

Comment: If you don't want more of a hint, don't read this comment.  If you do: Start with $f(a) = b$ and compute the value of $f$ at the following numbers, using each to compute the next:  $1/a$, $(a+1)/a$, $a/(a+1)$, $-a/(a+1)$, $1/(a+1)$, $a+1$.  Now, can you find the last one a different way?

Comment: Okay , i find a cycle and the fact that $f(a)=2a-b$ so i solved for $b$ and found that $a=b$, so $f(a)=a$  for all $a≠0,-1$ and i found then $f(0)$ and $ f(1)$ so my conclusion was $f(a)=a$ for all reels $a$ thank you guys so much!  but my question is: can i suppose that $f(a)=b$ in the first place? Doesn't that require $f$ to be surjective or something

Comment: No assumption required.  You let $a$ be an arbitrary real number (other than 0 or $-1$).  Then you define $b$ to be $f(a)$.  That's just a notational shortcut--you could just write it as $f(a)$ throughout the whole solution rather than $b$.  Then you solve for $b$ and find that $b = a$, so $f(a) = a$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that $f(n)=n$ in 3 to get the value for reciprocals of all integers.  Then use 2 to get reciprocals plus integers.  I believe you need to be told that $f$ is continuous.  Without that I don't think you can say anything about the value at irrationals.

Comment: No im not told that $f$ is continuous

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just saw Dan Vellerman's proof (hint actually), which is very elegant, and which I did not think of.

I will nevertheless add the proof that $f(x)=x$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ because the induction techniques used might be useful for some.

Let's prove that $f(x)=x$ on $\mathbb{Q}$.

- Notice that $f(0) = -f(-0) = -f(0)$. Therefore $f(0)=0$.
- Let's prove $f(x+n)=f(x)+n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For $n=0$ this is obiously true. By induction $f(x+n+1) = f(x+1+n) = f(x+1)+n = f(x)+1+n = f(x) + n+1$. Therefore it is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
- Let us now prove $f\left( \frac{a}{b} \right) = \frac{a}{b}$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\mathbb{N}^+$. Suppose that $a\in\mathbb{N}$ and continue by induction on $a$.  If $|a|=0$ we reduce to the first case above. Otherwise:

$$
f\left( \frac{a}{b} \right) = \frac{f\left( \frac{b}{a}\right) }{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2} = \frac{f\left( \frac{(b \mod a) + \lfloor \tfrac{b}{a} \rfloor a}{a} \right) }{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2} = \frac{f\left( \frac{(b \mod a) }{a} + \left\lfloor \tfrac{b}{a} \right\rfloor \right) }{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2} = \frac{f\left( \frac{(b \mod a) }{a}\right) + \left\lfloor \tfrac{b}{a} \right\rfloor  }{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2} = \frac{\frac{(b \mod a) }{a} + \left\lfloor \tfrac{b}{a} \right\rfloor  }{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2} = \frac{\frac{b}{a}}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2} = \frac{a}{b}
$$
Note that the induction step was used in saying that $f\left(\frac{b \mod a}{a}\right) = \frac{b \mod a}{a}$ since $(b \mod a) < a$.

Finally if $a<0$ then $f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = f\left(-\frac{|a|}{b}\right) = -f\left(\frac{|a|}{b}\right) = -\frac{|a|}{b}= \frac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 1):

> $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}(\text{odd}), f(x+1)=f(x)+1, f(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{f(x)}{x^2}.$

\begin{align}
& f\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+1 = \dfrac{f(x)}{x^2}+1. \tag{1}\label{1} \\
& f\left(\dfrac{x+1}{x}\right)=\dfrac{f\left(\dfrac{x}{x+1}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{x}{x+1}\right)^2}\\
& = \dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x^2}f\left( 1-\dfrac{1}{x+1} \right) \\
& = \dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x^2}\left(1-f\left(\dfrac{1}{x+1}\right)\right) \\
& = \dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x^2}\left(1-\dfrac{f(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}\right) \\
& = \dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x^2}\left(1-\dfrac{f(x)+1}{(x+1)^2}\right). \tag{2}\label{2} \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & (\ref{1}) = (\ref{2}) \Rightarrow \dfrac{f(x)}{x^2}+1=\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x^2}\left( 1-\dfrac{f(x)+1}{(x+1)^2} \right). \\
\Rightarrow \; & f(x)+x^2=(x+1)^2-f(x)-1, 2f(x)=2x, \boxed{f(x)=x}.
\end{align}